# Put hard disk to sleep when possible but i have SSD

Tags: ssd, battery, sleep-wake

I have a question, I gave the update to the latest version of Ventura and I saw that appeared the option of "put hard disk to sleep when possible "the battery section. I have a 2019 13" max out macbook and I have the following questions:

1. I know that an SSD is always on, there is no option to be in sleep, how does it turn it off?
2. Does the battery really save this feature?
3. It increases the life of the SSD?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Putting disks to sleep is a function used on traditional spinning media, not SSDs.  When you put the hard drive to sleep, it will "spin down" the drive to conserve power.

Your SSD cannot spin down so it will only go to "sleep" if your Mac is put into hibernation where data is written to storage and then the whole machine goes into a very low power mode to conserve battery.

So, for all practical purposes, it doesn't turn off, it has no effect on your battery and it won't increase the life of the SSD.